# Yeoman angular generator and npm install

Tags: angularjs, node.js, yo

I have created a VM for a mean stack. The install of which went with no issues. node.js and others have been installed.

I am using angular-fullstack to generate a boiler plate. I am baffled by what happens when npm install is run. I see that the system downloading all the dependencies but it's not stored in node_modules folder. I believe it's being stored in the global folder. When I try to run the stack from the local folder it says missing dependencies of almost everything.

I tried sudo, fixing permissions of global folder adding global folder to NODE_PATH but to no avail. I m still trying to figure why npm install is not installing in the local folder.

Thanks

===============

This is the error i am getting when i run npm isntall

ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename '/vagrant/meandev/nal_angular_dashboard/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-typeof-symbol' -> '/vagrant/meandev/nal_angular_dashboard/node_modules/.babel-plugin-transform-es2015-typeof-symbol.DELETE'

Comment: When you do  `npm install` in wich part of your root are you doing that? 

 `C://user/documents` <-- example  or  `C://user/documents/projectFolder` ??

Comment: Hi Paulo I am doing npm install inside the project folder wherein the package.json is also there.

Answer (score 0):

Uma, I've installed successfully on my machine angular-fullstack generator and beside some ruby and sass problems I managed to successfully start the app.

The node_modules were installed by the generator in the main project folder ... the one shared by server(nodejs) and client app(angularjs).

Comment: hmm, i dont know what i am doing wrong but i am using mean stack created using vagrant. not sure whether that would have any bearing towards the issue i am facing.

Answer (score 0):

## I was able to resolve this issue.

My dev environment is as follows

Windows 7 host and Ubuntu running in Virtual box. Ubuntu was provisioned and managed by Vagrant.

I found that when the Node.js project is in the shared folder (between windows and Ubuntu) npm install and grunt were throwing a bunch of errors related to permissions. This was specific to my work computer which had defender, bitlocker and other stuff turned on. The moment i moved my folder to pure UBuntu folder everything worked.